# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new using AngularJs. I´m trying to show options from a json file, but the return message is:

"Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]"

This is my code:

```js
var sj = angular.module("factApp", []);

(function(app){
    "use strict";
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('values.json').success(function (datos){
        $scope.datos = data;
        });
});
});
```

```css
{
  "orders": {
    "odc": [
      {
        "id": "ABA",
        "coupons": [
          "1XY",
          "2XY",
          "3XY"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="row" ng-app="factApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <h1>Cupones</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in datos">
        <p>Orden: {{data.id}}</p><br>
        <p>Cupones {{data.coupons}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="testjson/fuctury.js"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong? Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: Shouldn't be `$scope.data = datos;`?

Comment: It should be `sj.controller` instead of `app.controller`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code, you should access the data property of the response, also you should use **`.then`** instead of **`success`**

```
sj.controller('appController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('values.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.datos = response.data.orders.odc;
    console.log($scope.datos);
  });
});
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvjUVyNRuRTmaL5RF82e?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry read more about how to create angular module and controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller